# Font not available in Reporting Services designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, fonts

We've got a report designed using the reporting services designer in Visual Studio 2008, that happens to use a non-standard TrueType font (i.e. not one installed with a Microsoft product).

The font has been deployed and is available in applications such as Microsoft Word, but for whatever reason, on a *few* machines, the font is not available either in the designer, or in the viewer. The font shows in Control Panel > Fonts and reports that it supports embeddability of "Print and preview".

Why might this be? The obvious conclusion would be that there is something "different" about the machines but I'm at a loss of where to start to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the font that was missing had been installed via a login script. Removing the font via Control Panel, and reinstalling the font (by drag/drop, instead of login script) seems to have resolved the issue.